# How to remove a mark set by iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm setting marks with iptables like  this

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.143 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

if I want to clear what I do is remove all with

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

instead of removing all the rules to clear this, how to remove a mark only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just delete that one rule.

`iptables -L -t mangle --line-numbers`

will give you a number for each rule in your mangle table, then use

```
iptables -t mangle -D POSTROUTING x
```

where x is the rule number where you defined the mark.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this syntax:

```
iptables -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.143 -j MARK --set-mark 10
```

(Note the -A changed to -D, everything else the same)

This format it useful if it is in your recent history which makes it easy to scroll back and change the A to a D. (ie, when you're testing a rule)

Comment: I have this code `iptables -t mangle -A wlan0_Outgoing -m mac --mac-source ${mac} -j MARK --set-mark 2`. Does change -A to a -D would remove this rule?

Comment: @Reigel Yes....

Comment: Note that this does not match the mark ID you provided with `--set-mark` when deleting the rule with `-D`. Any mark ID will delete the rule if everything else matches. Tested with Linux kernel 5.8.